# How to get hidden columns field name from Kendo Grid object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get hidden columns field names from Kendo Grid in JavaScript. Is there any way to get all hidden column filed names?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sample of what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `column` of the grid has a `hidden` attribute. You can access the columns and build an array of `field` items if the `hidden` attribute is true:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var columns = grid.columns;

var hiddenFields = [];
for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
  if(columns[i].hidden) {      
    hiddenFields.push(columns[i].field);
  }
}
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/oBuse/2) to demonstrate.